# What is the good source to study advanced custom coding in Mathematica

Tags: performance-tuning, symbolic, system-performance

My question is, probably, too general ... I deal a lot with complicated symbolic evaluations, integrations, plotting. I have troubles with optimizing my codes. They come out way too slow. Google and *Mathematica* are really not very helpful with that. I go to *Mathematica* tutorials online, or on Youtube, I check *Mathematica* manuals available from official sources... And they try to teach me how to take a square root of 5 and plot a line (exaggerating, but just a bit).

On the other hand, I see all this witchcraft going on with custom codes...

```
FullSimplify[expr,ComplexityFunction -> (Count[#, Power[_, _?Negative],  
Infinity] &),Assumptions -> d > 0]
```

for example. So, I feel like there is a huge gap between the level of tutorials/manuals and the actual skills, required for getting anything close to serious from *Mathematica*. So, any sources, example codes (in particular) are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Leonid's book might help clear up some of the witchcraft, which hopefully just looks like sleight of hand once you know what's going on - [http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/)

Comment: Have a look at [where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice) and perhaps [what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)